# ReferenceError: withTagName is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/locating_elements/ says:

> Selenium 4 brings Relative Locators which are previously called as
> Friendly Locators. This functionality was added to help you locate
> elements that are nearby other elements. The Available Relative
> Locators are:
>
> ```
> above
> below
> toLeftOf
> toRightOf
> near
> ```
>
> findElement method now accepts a new method withTagName() which
> returns a RelativeLocator.

It also provides a JavaScript example for each of the locators:

```
let emailAddressField = driver.findElement(By.id('email'));
let passwordField = await driver.findElement(withTagName('input').below(emailAddressField));
```

When I try this myself:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, util } = require("selenium-webdriver")
const until = require("selenium-webdriver/lib/until")
const firefox = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox")
const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options()

async function run() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build()

    await driver.get("https://www.google.com")

    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("lnXdpd")), 4000).then(
        async function(titleElement) {
            driver.findElement(withTagName("div").below(titleElement)).then(function() {
                console.log("TODO")
                driver.quit()
            })
        },
        function() {
            console.warn("Failed to find element")
            driver.quit()
        }
    )
}
run()
```

I get:

> (node:21616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: withTagName is not defined

My dependencies from package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-beta.4"
  }
```

I tried finding some documentation about this on https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/, but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Searching around some more, I found that [a test involving this API was fixed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8375), so surely it must work.

What am I missing?

Comment: ```async function(titleElement) {``` just curious, it looks like you only declare this function and not calling it.

Comment: Entirely possible, I'm completely new to this promise stuff. :) Though my understanding is that the return value of `findElement()` is a [WebElementPromise](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElementPromise.html), and its `then()` function has two parameters (callbacks?): `opt_onFulfilled` and `opt_onRejected`.

Comment: You should study the promise and then async await. Otherwise, you will be confused. It is difference from callback

Comment: I think my usage of it is correct, though. If you know how to do it, please share that information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `withTagName` was missing from the `require` line:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, util, withTagName } = require("selenium-webdriver")
```

Comment: Good to hear! I recommend you should use await in your codes as it is more readable in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I have found my code becoming difficult to follow, so I'll give it a try.